# Carga de Componentes Vue.js de fichero único en visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mvc, vue.js, webpack

Tengo una solución MVC en VS2015 en la cual utilizo vue.js para generar el binding de datos, para poder utilizar componentes en un fichero con extensión .vue instale webpack.

En primera instancia decidí generar un archivo js por cada archivo .vue con un config tal que así:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// build an object that looks like 
// {
//      "filename": "./filename.vue"
// }
// to list the entry points for webpack to compile.
function buildEntry() {
const reducer = (entry, file) => { entry[file.split(".").shift()] = 
`./Vue/${file}`; return entry; };

return fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "Vue"))
    .filter(file => file.endsWith(".vue"))
    .reduce(reducer, {});
}

module.exports = {
entry: buildEntry(),
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "Vue"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    library: "[name]"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader' },
    ],
}
}
```

con el config anterior podía usar un componente incluyendo su js en una vista, y añadiendolo usando:

```
 Vue.component("foo", foo);
```

Pero esto llego un punto en el que genera demasiados js y decidí unirlo.
para unirlo he utilizado este config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./Vue/BundleIndex.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./Vue/bundle.js",
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader' },
        ],
    }
}
```

y en bundleIndex.js tengo :

```
import foo from '.\\foo.vue'
import example from '.\\example.vue'
```

e intento usar los componentes como antes, y no funciona. Creo que hay algo del proceso que genera webpack que no entiendo.

Answer (score -1):

```
 import foo from './foo.vue'
 import example from './example.vue'
```

lo que tiene mal es la ruta al componente, el `./` significa el directorio actual.

Comment: La idea de las respuestas es explicar un poco cómo o por qué el código soluciona el problema, no es solo poner el código y ya.

Comment: En la línea del comentario de @Shaz, por favor, lee [answer]. Un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias, todavia no he leido como responder pero lo hare.